# Issue with Pool and Queue of multiprocessing module in Python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am new to multiprocessing of Python, and I wrote the tiny script below:

```
import multiprocessing
import os

def task(queue):
    print(100)

def run(pool):
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for i in range(os.cpu_count()):
        pool.apply_async(task, args=(queue, ))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    run(pool)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I am wondering why the task() method is not executed and there is no output after running this script. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is running, but it's dying with an error outside the main thread, and so you don't see the error.  For that reason, it's always good to `.get()` the result of an async call, even if you don't care about the result:  the `.get()` will raise the error that's otherwise invisible.

For example, change your loop like so:

```
tasks = []
for i in range(os.cpu_count()):
    tasks.append(pool.apply_async(task, args=(queue,)))
for t in tasks:
    t.get()
```

Then the new `t.get()` will blow up, ending with:

```
RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

In short, passing `Queue` objects to `Pool` methods isn't supported.

But you *can* pass them to `multiprocessing.Process()`, or to a `Pool` initialization function.  For example, here's a way to do the latter:

```
import multiprocessing
import os

def pool_init(q):
    global queue # make queue global in workers
    queue = q

def task():
    # can use `queue` here if you like
    print(100)

def run(pool):
    tasks = []
    for i in range(os.cpu_count()):
        tasks.append(pool.apply_async(task))
    for t in tasks:
        t.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=pool_init, initargs=(queue,))
    run(pool)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

On Linux-y systems, you can - as the original error message suggested - use process inheritance instead (but that's not possible on Windows).

Comment: Thanks. It really helps!